# why insert two same records and the transaction doesn't rollback

Tags: java, transactions

I make a basic project of javaweb, and add spring transaction configration on it, but it does not effect. before this, it work well. I searched a lot pages on net, those configurations are same as mine.

Expected result is nothing will be inserted, but a record was inserted.

Please help me find that where the problem is, thank u

my serviceimpl path is:com.lidaning.sys.user.service.UserInfoServiceImpl

```
 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>    
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>

 <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="txPointcut" expression="execution(* com.lidaning.sys.user.service..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="txPointcut" advice-ref="txAdvice"/>
 </aop:config>
```

```
@Override
public void insertUser(UserInfo u) {
    u.setId("1");
    u.setName("lidaning");
    u.setPassword("***");
    userInfoDao.insertUser(u);
    userInfoDao.insertUser(u);  //occur exception 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason. Because spring loaded the serviceBean twice(spring, springMVC), and that caused service lost the characteristics of transactions. When I separated controller from applicationcontext and putt it in springMVC, it works.